# use findAllAsync two times in code

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to search a webpage to find two string. I use this code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.findAllAsync("str1");
        webView.findAllAsync("str2");
    }
});
```

and this FindListener :

```
public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
    if(numberOfMatches > 0)     
      (...) //do something
}
```

but in this case `onFindResultReceived` is called only for *str2*, and if `numberOfMatches` for *str1* is greater than 0 nothing is done. what is the reason and what should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAllAsync(java.lang.String))

> Finds all instances of find on the page and highlights them, asynchronously. Notifies any registered WebView.FindListener. Successive calls to this will cancel any pending searches.

In other words, your second call cancels the first. The solution will be to wait until each search is complete to start the next. Below is one example that could acheive the desired result for any number of strings

```
private int mCurrentSearchIndex = -1;
private String mSearchTerms = { "str1", "str2" } 

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        nextSearch();
    }
}); 

private void nextSearch() {
    mCurrentSearchIndex ++; //the fisrt tiem this is called the index gets set to 0
    if (mCurrentSearchIndex < mSearchTerms.length) {
        //get the search string corresponding to this index and then search it
        webView.findAllAsync(mSearchTerms[mCurrentSearchIndex]);
    }
}

public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
    if (isDoneCounting) {
        if (numberOfMatches > 0) {   
            ...
        }
        //here we know the previous find finished, so its safe to start another
        nextSearch();
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can I search for more than one string in a webpage?

Comment: You have to wait for them to finish. I just added an example

Comment: how to use different color for each type of highlighted string